# Two INNER JOIN ODBC MSAccess exception with query

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have a problem.. I want to connect to my database with odbc to msAccess from c# app. I have got exception error. Please my query... It should work but apparently I am doing something in wrong way here..

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error
>   (missing operator) in query expression
>   '[autoResults].[autoStats]=[autoStats].ID INNER JOIN [users] ON
>   [users].ID=[autoStats].userID

```
string queryString =@"
SELECT [erNumber].[autoResults],
[passedTesting].[autoResults],
[releaseVersion].[autoStats],
[lastFunction].[autoResults],
[startTime].[autoStats],
[Name].[users]
FROM [autoStats] 
INNER JOIN [autoResults] 
 ON [autoResults].[autoStats]=[autoStats].ID
INNER JOIN [users]
 ON [users].ID=[autoStats].userID
WHERE [erNumber].[autoResults] LIKE '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access can be fussy about multiple JOINs and often requires that they be enclosed in parentheses. So instead of

```sql
FROM [autoStats] 
INNER JOIN [autoResults] 
 ON [autoResults].[autoStats]=[autoStats].ID
INNER JOIN [users]
 ON [users].ID=[autoStats].userID
```

try

```sql
FROM 
    (
        [autoStats] 
        INNER JOIN 
        [autoResults] 
            ON [autoResults].[autoStats]=[autoStats].ID
    )
    INNER JOIN 
    [users]
        ON [users].ID=[autoStats].userID
```

Comment: To my knowledge, JET always requires the brackets when you have more than one `JOIN`

Comment: Thanks! but.. in that way I have got following..

> ERROR [07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few
> parameters. Expected 6.

Any solution for this? I tried to separate INNER JOINS with ( ) but it is not working still.